# find why reading a png failed with libpng C

Tags: c, error-handling, libpng, gcc4.8

I was writing a image loader using libpng.

My question is about error handling, is there anyway to find out what was the cause of the error?
I have access to a string with the cause, but is there a way to find the error by other means like an error code or something...

I don't think comparing strings is the solution.

if it matters:
compiler: mingw-tdm gcc 4.8.1
libpng: libpng 1.6
os: windows 7 x64
language: C

Comment: libpng only returns error strings, not error numbers.

Comment: well... then comparing string might indeed be the solution.. thank you.